# Adjective for a type of conversation where no real information is conveyed but rather the speakers are establishing a connection.

Tags: adjectives, conversation

There is an english word (adj) that refers to a type of conversation where no real real information is being conveyed but rather the speakers are establishing a connection.

A casual conversation about the weather between two speakers who don't know each other well would be an example.

Comment: You are probably looking for https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_talk or http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chitchat

Comment: @SpencerSimpson I'd upvote that as an answer.

Comment: An adjective? As in "The strangers had a __________ conversation." or similar?

Comment: Schmoosing, jawboning, nattering, confabulatory. Although most common is small talk.

Answer (score 2):

[Small talk](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/small%20talk) is the most common label I know of.

> informal, friendly conversation about unimportant subjects

Also to consider:
[chitchat](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chitchat)

> friendly conversation about things that are not very important

Answer (score 2):

The technical term for this is *phatic*. From [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/phatic):

> denoting speech used to express or create an atmosphere of shared feelings, goodwill, or sociability rather than to impart information.

Answer (score 1):

I'd call it **polite conversation**. It's difficult to find good references for this use, which is a bit idiomatic. Polite conversation can also be a literal thing, and you can find plenty of advise on how to conduct polite conversation at parties etc. The alternatives tend to be dismissive regarding the lack of heft, and there is no reason to be dismissive towards this.

Answer (score 0):

Casual, cursory, superficial, disinterested, mechanical...